# Haproxy and upstart scripting

Tags: haproxy, upstart

I am new to HA Proxy and Upstart Scripting. I am using, HA Proxy version 1.4.18 2011/09/16. I am trying to write an upstart script that will keep haproxy alive in case haproxy dies. This is what I have so far:
    script
     if [ $(pgrep haproxy) ]; then
    restart haproxy;
     else
    start haproxy;
     fi
    end script

Does look like a legible code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make it nerdest and oneline script:

```
[ $(pgrep haproxy) ] && restart haproxy || start haproxy
```

BTW.. the easiest and best way to make it is to use an init.d custom script like this: http://mattiasgeniar.be/2010/11/04/a-custom-init-d-start-up-script-for-haproxy-start-stop-restart-reload-checkconfig/

Comment: That's fancy I will give it a shot. Thank you:)